# Javascript/AJAX/jQuery - Object Expected Line 1 only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

http://pastie.org/856698

Anyone have any idea why the script is causing this error? It doesn't throw an error in Firefox, only IE.

Any ideas?

A link to the final script can be found at
http://www.proskimboarding.com/codingtest/Public/registration.php

Comment: if you are linking jquery why create your own xmlhttprequest? jquery can deal with all that for you $get $post and $ajax

Comment: even after submitting the form, you aren't getting an error?

Comment: My mistake. I removed that comment. I am getting the error in Firefox though. Getting 'regSubmit is not defined'

Comment: Hmm I didn't know you could edit a question if you're just a visitor.  I wanted to change the tags and title as well.

Comment: Yes SO allows you to edit pretty much anything.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't getting that error in firefox.. it would have led me to the problem right away.  Simple typo!  Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: I made my comment an answer so that you can mark as answered and closed.

Comment: @Richard Harrington - Make sure to accept answers after the problem's resolved, the check beside the one that helped you does that

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Pharabus is right, if you have jQuery available, use $.ajax instead of building your own http request, it can save you a *lot* of code (hint: [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html)).
Then you have `<form method="post" action="JavaScript: regSubmit()">` but your function is named `submitReg()`, so that's causing the error Dustin Laine mentioned.
Third of all: why using `onClick="JavaScript:submitReg()"` if you already trigger this function on the form action? This will probably cause two identical requests for no reason.